# Supported locations for merchants - what does it mean?

Tags: android, google-play

I live in country that Google does not support for merchants. I've been checking out list of supported locations when I found this:

> Please remember:
> If you are not located in any of the countries listed above, or do not own the required bank account for receiving payments, Google may not be able to pay for the sales in that account by any other means.

I'm wondering - what does it mean? I have to live in one of those countries, or I just have to own bank account in one of those location? I'll be happy and thankful for any answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means google doesn't have the payment service in countries other then that list.

The merchant accounts are only be created for the merchant who is the resident in the listed country and also having the account in recognized Bank of that country.